# Overriding default behavior of links using JQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to override all 'a' tags in a document with a specific class to prevent their default behavior and send a javascript alert. Here is my code so far:

```
$('.specific-class').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.onclick('alert("hello world")');
});
```

This code stops the links from firing, as it should, but it doesn't send my 'hello world' message.

Does anyone know the appropriate syntax to make the alert fire when the links are clicked? Let me know if I can provide any additional information!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error was using `event.onclick();` instead of just `alert()` which will fire when you click
Here is the snippet:

```js
$('.specific-class').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("hello world");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="specific-class">hi you, click me.</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `alert` inside handler as this function will be executed on the click of anchor.

```
$('.specific-class').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hello world");
});
```

Or you can also update the `onclick` attribute value on page load

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.specific-class').attr('onclick', 'alert("Hello World!"); return false;');
});
```